# how to deserialize a json object to collection using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize a json like this

```
{
    "0":{"name":"Alice"},
    "1":{"name":"Bob"}
}
```

to a java collection( set or list, **not map**). 
I want to change the default behavior of `CollectionDeserializer` to support this and config it as a global configuration. Any way to to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have this structure (an object as a container and not an array, which could be handled much easier):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"0\":{\"name\":\"Alice\"}, \"1\":{\"name\":\"Bob\"}}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode obj = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> userEntries = obj.fields();
        while(userEntries.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> userEntry = userEntries.next();
            System.out.println(userEntry.getKey() + " => " + userEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set this behavior as a global config? I use it in spring web mvc project, I don't want to write this deserialize code everywhere.

Comment: yes, see section: "Create a custom ObjectMapper by extending the default Jackson ObjectMapper.

": http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this task using gson api.
The code is as follows:

```
String yourJson = "{\"0\":{\"name\":\"Alice\"}, \"1\":{\"name\":\"Bob\"}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type tarType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>(){
}.getType(); 
gson.fromJson(yourJson, tarType);
```

For this you need to add following:
com.google.gson.Gson

Answer (score 0):

Why not to turn your JSON document into an array as:

```
{"persons":[{"name":"Alice"},{"name":"Bob"}]}
```

Then define a corresponding JSON schema (assuming `PersonArray` is the file name):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",  
  "description": "Some description",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "persons" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/person" }
    }
  },

  "definitions": {
    "person" : {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "A person",
        "properties": {
            "name": { "type": "string" }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and take advantage of Jackson Data Binding API by using `jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin` Maven plugin to generate POJOs in Java (alternatively, you can manually implement POJOs).

Once POJOs are generated, you can use ObjectMapper to deserialise JSON document in the following way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PersonArray personArray = mapper.readValue(serialisedJsonDocument, PersonArray.class);
```

The elements of your JSON document will be stored inside `PersonArray` object as:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

You could also add additional properties to the `Person` object if you needed.